# corrupted directories, problem in deleting them

Tags: linux, directory, rm, character-encoding

There is a directory in my Linux system because of some software malfunction some directories with junk name as you can see below is created, I have problem in deleting them,

```
$ ll
total 1532
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Apr 19 16:56 -?$??
drwxrwxr-x 248 sensage sensage   4096 Apr 23 11:37 .
drwxrwxr-x  99 sensage sensage   4096 Apr 16 14:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Apr  6 14:54 }???;?
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Apr 19 03:01 }??=?|
-rw-r--r--   1 sensage sensage     88 Apr 22 13:37 $
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Apr  2 12:43 ?
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Mar 20 02:51 ?=??&?
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Apr 11 08:40 ?;%??;
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Apr 14 09:38 ?:????
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Mar 22 17:21 ?(?>~?
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Apr  1 13:45 ?[???%
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Apr  3 14:03 ?@????
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Apr 12 16:18 ??
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Apr 17 16:38 ??&???
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Mar 25 02:43 ??+???
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Apr 19 00:46 Ü¡?,??
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Mar 28 18:54 ÚŸ??"?
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Mar 27 01:04 ???(?
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Apr 19 22:41 ??Í¨?`
drwxr-xr-x   2 sensage sensage   4096 Apr 15 11:44 ?????-
```

as you can see directory names in blue. when I want to delete them  I get below error:

```
$ ls -1  | grep -v 20 | xargs rm -rf 
xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
rm: invalid option -- ¼
Try `rm ./'-¼$Þ¸Í'' to remove the file `-\274$\336\270\315'.
Try `rm --help' for more information.
```

what should I do with them?

Comment: Having such file/directory names would also urge me to first run `fsck` on the filesystem after having made sure I have a backup.

Comment: Do you need to examine the directory listing to determine which items should be deleted, or can you delete all items there?

Comment: where's the blue directory?

Comment: sorry, blue directories are those with junk characters like ?;%??; all of them I mistaken by saying blue

Comment: actually it doesn't need `fsck`, I know the cause,there is a script which according to  data make directory,It worked fine till the data encoding changed and I was a disaster @Ruslan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ls` will print non-ASCII characters (or rather, characters not supported in the current locale) as `?`.  This is one of the reasons why parsing the output of `ls` is a bad thing to do.  The output from `ls` is meant to be *looked at*.  In some cases, like this, those are not the actual names that exist in the filesystem.

Try instead something like (these will delete *all* files and directories, including `/path/to/dir`)

```
rm -rf /path/to/dir
```

or

```
find /path/to/dir -delete
```

or

```
find /path/to/dir -exec rm -rf {} +
```

or

```
find /path/to/dir -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Modify to fit your needs. To only delete files, add `-type f` after the path in the `find` examples, for example.

Doing just `rm -rf *` *inside that directory* (that's *important*, the current working directory must be the directory whose files and directories you want to delete) may also be enough.

See also [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative method to easily remove directories and/or files named with non-printing characters, is to ascertain the inode number of the errant directories (or files) and using it, delete the directory (or file):

```
cd /mypath || exit 1
ls -il    #...to show the inode <number> in the leftmost column output
find . -xdev -inum <number> -exec rm -rf {} +
```

The `-xdev` option insures that `find` does not descend directories on other filesystems.  Inode numbers are guaranteed to be unique only within a filesystem.

Add '-f' as an additional `find` option to return only files.